# how to integrate gatling with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gatling

I want to use gatling for load testing integrating it with jenkins. Can anyone supply me the step by step methods for doing that. I have a very little knowledge of using maven and sbt.

Answer (score 6):

I think this question is very important and relevant so although OP already found a solution, I'm writing a detailed answer. I have experience with integrating a Gatling-Maven project with Jenkins through Git, so I'm going with this combination.

### Running Gatling project from command line

The project needs to be able to run from terminal with some build tool, which in this case is Maven. The [Gatling Maven plugin](https://gatling.io/docs/current/extensions/maven_plugin/) is a suitable tool for this. To import it, include the following snippet in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>MANUALLY_REPLACE_WITH_LATEST_VERSION</version>
    <configuration>
      <simulationClass>MANUALLY_REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SIMULATION_CLASS</simulationClass>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**Note 1**: The versions of the `gatling-charts-highcharts` dependency and the `gatling-maven-plugin` plugin do not have to match.

**Note 2**: Replace the value in the `simulationClass` tag with your simulation class as it is in the package statement (e.g. `com.example.my.SimulationClass`).

After doing this, you should be able to run the project from the command line with the following commands:

```
mvn clean package
mvn gatling:test
```

*Alternatively, you can use the [Scala Maven plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.alchim31.maven/scala-maven-plugin). In this case you need to run your main class (where you build your Gatling Properties).*

### Creating a Jenkins pipeline for your Gatling-Maven project

I assume you have a Jenkins environment set up with the Jenkins Maven plugin installed. See [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_maven_setup.htm) to learn more about the plugin part.

#### Pipeline script

There are three ways to define what a Jenkins pipeline does:

1. Through Blue Ocean UI
2. Through classic Jenkins UI
3. By creating a Jenkinsfile in your project

I think the 3rd option is the most practical one because this way the pipeline script is committed to source control. This makes it more transparent and easier to maintain. 

*See [this page](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/) to learn more about the other options.*

So create a file in your project root directory with the name `Jenkinsfile` and no extension. Paste this script into it:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Maven build") {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B clean package'
            }
        }
        stage("Gatling run") {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn gatling:test'
            }
            post {
                always {
                    gatlingArchive()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Commit this file and push the commit into a remote repository like Github or Gitlab. This is how Jenkins is going to be able to read the `Jenkinsfile`.

#### Creating pipeline

To create a pipeline job in Jenkins, go to your Jenkins dashboard and click on "New Item" on the top of the left menu bar. Name the job and choose Pipeline as a type. Click OK.

On the pipeline config page, scroll down to the `Pipeline` header and select "Pipeline script from SCM" in the `Definition` drop-down. A dropdown appears to choose a version control system. Choose Git. Paste your repository URL into the related field (the one you use to clone your repo). You can use either HTTP or SSH protocol but pay attention to set the credentials accordingly. A red error message will show up if Jenkins cannot access the repository. Optionally, you can set the branch that you want to build (make sure you have the Jenkinsfile on that branch).

Once all set, click Save.

#### Gatling Jenkins plugin

At this point, Jenkins should be able to build and run the project, but to see the reports, the [Gatling Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gatling) needs to be installed (this is what executes the `gatlingArchive()` line in the pipeline script. It also provides ways to compare results from the last 15 builds, which is very useful.

To install this plugin, go back to your Jenkins dashboard and click on "Manage Jenkins" on the left menu bar. Search for Gatling and install the plugin. Restart Jenkins when asked about it.

### Using the Jenkins pipeline job

Go to the dashboard page of your new pipeline. (The left menu should contain a "Gatling" option by now.) Click on "Build". When the build is ready, click on "Gatling" on the left and scroll down to the bottom of the page. You can open the Gatling report by clicking on the link. As more and more builds are run and added to your history, all the reports will be available here and the graphs are going to contain data from the last 15 builds.

Comment: It was needed to replaced mvn -B clean "package" to "test" as my project only contains test files, not main package files.

Answer (score 1):

I have run the gatling project with maven, then it can be integrated with jenkins.
please go through the links below

http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.2/extensions/maven_plugin.html

https://github.com/gatling/gatling-maven-plugin-demo

Comment: Please update your link to point to a modern version of the documentation, not a release candidate from 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you already found the way yourself but will answer with short steps for those who are still looking for some more detailed tutorial.

To integrate Gatling and Jenkins you probably want to achieve 2 things.

First, to be able to run the tests via one line shell command (as soon as you can run the test via a shell command, you don't need anything else to run the performance scrips). And yes, you are right. Gatling maven plugin works great for these needs. All you need is just follow the example by this link:
https://github.com/gatling/gatling-maven-plugin-demo

Second, it is always better to have some visibility on build results in Jenkins itself. As soon as you have your performance tests as a step of Continuous Delivery/Deployment pipeline, it is better to provide a visibility on metrics trends. For this, you can start with this page:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/gatling. Jenkins plugin can provide you much better visibility on Gatling tests results right in the Jenkins CI.

Btw, we are starting some series of posts which will be dedicated to Gatling usage and we are going to publish step by step tutorials on how to use Gatling as a step for you continuous integration pipeline so stay tuned! 
https://www.blazemeter.com/gatling

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a simple integration among Gatling and travis, I'm using a existing plugin for gatling, if you are interested take a look overhere https://github.com/enriquezrene/gatling-tutorial-sbt

Comment: I couldn't find this project but it helped me to find https://github.com/atdi/gatling-tutorial

Comment: Sorry, the above URL was changed, this is the new one: https://github.com/enriquezrene/gatling-tutorial-sbt